# CSS Don't style empty input titles

Tags: css

I'm working with a CMS which allows you to add a tooltip to input boxes.

So this one has tooltip "Please enter your phone number".

```
<input name="var_customerphone" title="Please enter your phone number" />
```

and this one is emtpy

```
<input name="var_customername" title="" >
```

Here's my css which changes the cursor to help

```
input[type="text"][title] { cursor: help; }
```

My problem is this, the above code will show the help cursor for both inputs above, even though the second one doesn't contain any help text in the tooltip.

Is there any way to put some conditional code on the css to only show the help cursor if title is not empty?

Something along the lines of: `input[type="text"][title !=""] { cursor: help; }`

I have no control over the CMS so title will be outputted regardless if it contains any text or not.

thanks

Comment: You could use JavaScript to detect the empty titles and apply a class that controls the behavior of the hover state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
input[type="text"]:not([title=""]) { cursor: help; }
```

Note: According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp), IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector.

Comment: To improve your question add the compatibility of that selector

Answer (score 4):

Without using `:not` and increasing a bit compatibility with older browser (it works also on  `IE7`):

```
input[type="text"][title] { 
  cursor: help; 
} 

/* revert style for empty titles */
input[type="text"][title=""] { 
  cursor: default; 
}
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdGiq

Comment: you're welcome: of course `:not` would be my choice too, but unfortunately IE8 still has too many  users